# Converting areas of measure - Rounding

Tags: python, math

I have an old program that I am trying to replicate in Odoo 10. I am Stuck converting sq meters to linear meters with rounding. This is for rolls of carpet. The width of the carpet is 4M, Room width 9x5M. To get SQ meters I multiple Room width by Room Lenght which is 45sqm then divide by 4 which is the width of the carpet for Linear which is 11.25.

The Linear is 11.25 but I can't figure out how they are getting 15. The supplier does not want to be cutting carpet so the program is doing some kind of rounding or calculation based on the width of carpet. To get square units required it then multiply Linear x Width (15x4 = 60)
(The Floor width text in the picture should be Carpet width)
[image]

I am using below code for getting Room squared but can't figure out the math to even attempt the Linear conversion.

```
@api.onchange('roomwidth')
    def _onchange_squaremtr(self):
        self.sqfeet = (self.roomwidth or 1) * (self.roomlength or 1)



    @api.onchange('roomlength')
    def _onchange_roomlenght(self):
        self.sqfeet = (self.roomwidth or 1) * (self.roomlength or 1)
```

Here is another example.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They just fill room rectangle along short edge (perhaps to make shorter pieces rather than long ones).

w=4, room 9x5: three pieces A=4x5, B=4x5, C=4x5 and cut the last one to make 4x1 band

```
 A A A A A
 A A A A A
 A A A A A
 A A A A A  
 B B B B B
 B B B B B
 B B B B B
 B B B B B
 C C C C C
 ---------  cut
 C C C C C
 C C C C C
 C C C C C
```

w=6, room 13x8: three pieces A=6x8, B=6x8, C=6x8 and cut the last one to make 6x1 band

```
import math
def calccarpet(wdt, roomwdt, roomhgt):
    longer = max( roomwdt, roomhgt)
    shorter = min( roomwdt, roomhgt)
    numpieces = math.ceil(longer / wdt)
    carpetarea = numpieces * wdt * shorter
    return carpetarea

print(calccarpet(4, 5, 9))
print(calccarpet(6, 13, 8))
>>> 
60
144
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a factor of "Allowing x% wastage" in the scenario . Even if carpet is needed only 45 Sq. Units but we need to add wastage quantity percentage.

Ex. Width = 9 and length = 5

Sq Units = 9*5 = 45

Total Sq Units = 45 + ( 45 * X%)/100 = 60 Sq. Units

Here X (Allow Wastage) = 33.33 %

Kindly check if there is any wastage quantity margins.